# Is there a reason to ever choose sender: Any when creating an @IBAction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

The sender type is set to `Any` by default when you use IB/storyboards in Xcode to create an `IBAction` linking the interface object (e.g. button) with the method in the code file.

Since you are doing this from the interface to the code, Xcode should know by the interface what type of control you are using, for example a `UIButton`, and so why does it automatically set the sender to the `Any` type and not to `UIButton` specifically?

Is there any reason to leave it as `Any` and not change it to the `UIButton` type instead at the point of creation? Either when you do it from the interface to the code, or when you create the `IBAction` in the code first?

Basic example of the code you get when hooking up a button to your view controller, despite control clicking from the button on the interface:

```
@IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's an unreasonable default. If your function only applies to a single UI control, then the `sender` should be as strongly typed as possible.

Technically, you *could* define a single `@IBAction`, and bind it to multiple UI controls, of different types. But even in such a case, a more specific type like `NSView` would be more appropriate than `Any`.

Comment: Very debatable... for the OP's specific `func playAgain(_ sender: Any)`, it's entirely possible one might want to "play again" when current play is finished, in which case we could call (from the view controller, for example) `playAgain(self)`. The func might take a different action if it is called from a button or from the VC. One could argue "the *play* code should be in a separate func, and the button's `@IBAction` should call ***that*** func," but that's a whole other discussion of code structure. There are many reasons why `Any` (or `Any?`) could be preferable.

Comment: @DonMag "the play code should be in a separate func, and the button's @IBAction should call that func," yeah, exactly this. I would only use the `@IBAction` to interact with items bound in Interface Builder. `@IBAction` imposes restrictions on the function (it's implicitly `@objc`, it can't take any other args, and it can't return anything) to even be considered for anything else.